# Grouping SQL data into half hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

### The Problem

I have a table in MS SQL server which is a table of datetimes and values as seen in the image below:

[image: screenshot of data]

So for each half hour period the value doesn't change, so for example between 00:30 and 01:00 the value is 27.45 and then the value changes to 50 after 01:00.

This data is a snapshot of a larger table with timestamps covering an entire day(s). Each value is always the same over a time period of 30 minutes so for example the values in the myValue column between 16:00 and 16:30 will always be the same value.

### My Query

I want to select all of the data for the previous day and return it as half hour time periods, so based on the image above I would return:

[image: The result I want]

I do not have much to offer in the way of code as I really do not know how to do this so I only have the basic select statement, i have done it in c# but i wont go into that as its querying the database way too many times:

```
SELECT timestamp, myValue FROM myTable
WHERE [timestamp] BETWEEN '2020-04-16T00:00:00Z' AND '2020-04-16T23:59:59Z'
ORDER BY [timestamp] ASC
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Managing date/time values in SQL Server is often trickier than necessary.  One method is to extract the date and then manipulate the minutes:

```
SELECT dateadd(minute,
               datepart(hour, timestamp) * 60 + (datepart(minute, timestamp) / 30) * 30,
               convert(datetime, convert(date, timestamp))
              ) as half_hour,
       MAX(myValue)
FROM myTable
WHERE [timestamp] >= '2020-04-16' AND
      [timestamp] < '2020-04-17'
GROUP BY dateadd(minute,
                 datepart(hour, timestamp) * 60 + (datepart(minute, timestamp) / 30) * 30,
                 convert(datetime, convert(date, timestamp))
                )
ORDER BY MIN(timestamp);
```

If you want this for *yesterday* without hardcoding the date, use:

```
where timestamp >= dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and
      timestamp < convert(date, getdate())
```

Comment: I get the following error 'The dateadd function requires 3 argument(s)', which I think might be related the number of brackets on the second line?

Comment: @Silentbob . . . Yes, an extra closing paren.

Comment: now i get 'The datepart minute is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.' which I am googling.

Comment: @Silentbob . . . Arrgh!  Microsoft really makes this more complicated than necessary.  Why don't they support `datetrunc()` and `interval`s?

Comment: i know, i always hate having to interact with dates in SQL